# Proof Verification for Homework

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

If $n$ is odd, then $n^2$ is odd.

$1$) $n = 2k + 1$ (Definition of an odd number)

$2$) $n^2 = (2k+1)^2 = (2k+1)(2k+1) = 4k^2 + 4k + 1$ (Distributive Property)

$3$) $4k^2 + 4k + 1 = 2(2k^2 + 2k) + 1$ (Distributive Property Again)

$4$) $2k^2 + 2k = K$ (K is an integer) (Integers are closed under addition and multiplication)

$5$) $n^2 = 2K + 1$ (Steps $2$ and $4$)

$6$) Therefore, if $n$ is odd, then $n^2$ is odd. (Definition of an odd number)

Comment: Your done at step 3. You have an even number plus 1 which is odd.

Comment: @Rod: It's only finished at step $3$ if we know that $2k^2+2k$ is an integer. It isn't hard to draw this conclusion, but we can't say that $2\alpha+1$ is odd for all numbers $\alpha.$

Comment: What? K is an integer to start with. So by closure we are done.

Comment: Yes. Closure is step 4. You did step 4, yourself, as a hidden argument.

Comment: @Rod My teacher demands you be specific (it's only an introductory course). I see what you mean, but he doesn't like us "skipping steps" which I would have to do to say it's proved at step 3.

Comment: @Cameron Buie.  I'm wrong you right. I see what you mean.

Comment: @user2840807 this proof is flawless m good job .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's excellent!  It's great that you added explanations as to what the steps mean.  Here's some nit-picks:

- You should mention that $k$ is an integer (as you did for $K$).
- Technically, deducing $(2k+1)(2k+1) = 4k^2 + 4k + 1$ uses distributivity twice: $$(2k+1)(2k+1) = 2k(2k+1)+(2k+1) = 4k^2 + 4k + 1.$$  (Both left- and right-distributivity.)  In fact, it also uses associativity and that $1$ is the multiplicative identity.  [This may or may not matter, depending on the level of rigor required.]
- It sounds like you're talking to a computer.  E.g. instead of writing

  > $1$) $n = 2k + 1$ (Definition of an odd number)
  >
  > $2$) $n^2 = (2k+1)^2 = (2k+1)(2k+1) = 4k^2 + 4k + 1$ (Distributive
  >   Property)

  consider writing

  > Since $n$ is an odd number, $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k$.  Consequently, $n^2=(2k+1)^2=(2k+1)(2k+1) = 4k^2 + 4k + 1$ by the distributive property.

  (unless your teacher insisted on an itemized approach).

Answer (score 0):

Well done! It looks just fine.